# Hide bar button (both left and right) from another ViewController?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationitem

I've two ViewController from first i've added two bar buttons to second ViewController. code here- `

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =
[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
  initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
  target:self
  action:@selector(backBtnAction)] autorelease];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =
[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
  initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
  target:callListViewCtrObj
  action:@selector(saveListNameAction)] autorelease];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];`
```

Now i want to remove these two buttons when done button clicked(i.e. saveListNameAction of callListViewCtrObj is called, see the code above), i've tried like this- `homeViewCtrObj.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
homeViewCtrObj.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem =nil;`
where homeViewCtrObj is object of first view controller.

Any suggestion or sample code will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CallListViewCtr create a property for HomeViewCtr

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) HomeViewCtr *homeView;
```

Now when you push this view makes sure to assign the newly created viewController to this property.

```
self.homeView = theNewViewControllerImAboutToPush;
```

Now you can use

```
self.homeView.navigatioItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
self.homeView.navigatioItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
```

I think you'll want to set homeView to nil when your done.

Comment: Another option is after you've initialized the view that's about to be pushed you can set the buttons to nil.

Comment: In that case you wouldn't use self

Comment: Curious which one? If you only need to do this once there's no need to use a property just use "theNewViewControllerImAboutToPush.leftbarbuttonitem = nil;"

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
```

Comment: @Hackmodford in my case i'm trying to hide bar buttons which is placed in HomeViewCtr, from a different ViewController(CallListViewCtr) then how can i point to buttons of HomeViewCtr from CallListViewCtr, using self.something(self indicate current object?)